# $\sup\{a^{r}\mid r<x; r\in\mathbb{Q}\}=\inf\{a^{s}\mid x<s; s\in\mathbb{Q}\}$ How to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

This proposition is a lemma related to another stage for defining exponential function $a^{x}$, in this case for reals, taking into account it is defined for rationals.

*Proposition* Let $a>1$ and $A, A^{*}$ be sets given by
\begin{align*}
 A &=\{a^{r}\mid r<x;\, r\in\mathbb{Q}\}\\
 A^{*} &=\{a^{s}\mid x<s;\, r\in\mathbb{Q}\}
\end{align*}
Then $\sup A=\inf A^{*}$.

*Proof (Partial).* We need to show that this sets are not empty and they are properly bounded. Let $\epsilon>0$, then $x-\epsilon<x<x+\epsilon$. By the density of the rationals in reals, there are $r',s'\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that
\begin{align*}
 x-\epsilon<r'<x<s'<x+\epsilon
\end{align*}
therefore
\begin{align*}
 a^{r'}\in A, &a^{s'}\in A^{*}\therefore\\
 A\neq\emptyset, &A^{*}\neq\emptyset
\end{align*}

Using the same $r',s'$ from the former argument we can see that
\begin{align*}
 a^{r'}\notin A^{*},\,a^{s'}\notin A
\end{align*}
since
\begin{align*}
 r'<x<s'
\end{align*}
By the last inequality
\begin{align*}
 a^{r'}<a^{s'}
\end{align*}
since $a>1$. But
\begin{align*}
 a^{r}<a^{s'},\,\forall r<x<s'
\end{align*}
therefore $a^{s'}$ is an upper bound for $A$. An analogous argument shows that
\begin{align*}
 a^{r'}<a^{s},\,\forall r'<x<s
\end{align*}
therefore $a^{r'}$ is a lower bound for $A^{*}$. By the supremum principle $A$ has supremum and $A^{*}$ has infimum.

We have $a^{r}<a^{s}$ for every $r<x$ and $x<s$. Then every $a^{s}$ is an upper bound for $A$. That is $\sup A\leq a^{s}$ by definition of supremum. But this means $\sup A$ is a lower bound for $A^{*}$. We conclude that $\sup A\leq\inf A^{*}$.

**But, how to discard the option $<$? I can't see it! What is sure, is that is impossible to be proved seeking for the reversed inequality, for always we have $a^{r}<a^{s}$.
The proof can continue trying to prove that $\sup A+\epsilon$, with $\epsilon>0$ is not a lower bound for $A^{*}$, what is the same as proving $\inf A^{*}-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound for $A$. The problem is how to write this in such a manner to compare with things like $a^{r}$.
Could anyone can help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Lemma.* Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $A_{x}=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}\mid r<x\}$ y $A_{x}^{*}=\{s\in\mathbb{Q}\mid x<s\}$. $A_{x}, A_{x}^{*}$ have supremum and infimum respectively, and these are equal.

*Proof.* Let $\epsilon>0$. Then exist, by the density of the rationals into the reals, $r',s'\in\mathbb{Q}$ such
   \begin{align*}
    x-\epsilon<r'<x<s'<x+\epsilon\therefore\\
    r'\in A_{x},\,s'\in A_{x}^{*}
   \end{align*}
   thus, both sets are not empty. Both sets are bounded by $x$: $A_{x}$ upper bounded and $A_{x}^{*}$ lower bounded. It follows that they have supremum and infimum respectívely.

Since $x$ is upper bound for $A_{x}$ and lower bound for $A_{x}^{*}$ then
   \begin{align*}
    r\leq\sup A_{x}\leq x\leq\inf A_{x}^{*}\leq s
   \end{align*}
   thus, if we suppose that
   \begin{align*}
    r\leq\sup A_{x}<x<\inf A_{x}^{*}\leq s
   \end{align*}
   we can find, again by the density of rationals, $r'',s''\in\mathbb{Q}$ such
   \begin{align*}
    r\leq\sup A_{x}<r''<x<s''<\inf A^{*}_{x}\leq s
   \end{align*}
   and we have $r''\in A_{x},\, s''\in A_{x}^{*}$, denying the fact that$\sup A_{x},\,\inf A_{x}^{*}$ are supremum and infimum respectively. That implies
   \begin{align*}
    r\leq\sup A_{x}=x=\inf A_{x}^{*}\leq s
   \end{align*}
   Then we conclude what we wanted to show.

*Lemma.* Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}, a>1$ fixed, $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $A_{x},A_{x}^{*}$ as in the previous lemma. Let, in addition, $\Sigma_{x}(a)=\{a^{r}\in\mathbb{R}\mid r\in A_{x}\}$ and $\Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)=\{a^{s}\in\mathbb{R}\mid s\in A^{*}\}$. $\Sigma_{x}(a), \Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)$ have supremum and infimum respectively, and these are equal.

*Proof.* Given that $A_{x},A_{x}^{*}$ are not empty, then $\Sigma_{x}(a), \Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)\neq\emptyset$. Also, given that $a>1$ and $r<x<s$ for every $r\in A_{x},\, s\in A_{x}^{*}$, then $a^{r}<a^{s}$. That means every $a^{s}$ is upper bound for $\Sigma_{x}(a)$ and every $a^{r}$ is lower bound for $\Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)$. It follows that $\Sigma_{x}(a), \Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)$ have supremum and infimum respectively.

By the previous lemma and bound, supremum and infimum definitions
   \begin{align*}
    a^{r} &<a^{s},\,\forall r\in A_{x},\, s\in A_{x}^{*}\therefore\\
    a^{r} &\leq\inf\Sigma_{x}^{*}(a),\,\forall r\in A_{x}\therefore\\
    \sup\Sigma_{x}(a) &\leq\inf\Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)
   \end{align*}
   But, since $\sup A_{x}=\inf A_{x}^{*}$ and a>1 and from exponential properties for rationals, then necessarily $\sup\Sigma_{x}(a)=\inf\Sigma_{x}^{*}(a)$. If that is not the case, we would conclude there is a number strictly lesser and, at the same time, strictly greater than $x$, what is not possible. Therefore it follows the lemma.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\sup A$ is strictly less than $\inf A^*$, then there is a $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sup A < y < \inf A^*$.  But either $x<y$ causing $y \in A^*$, $x = y$ causing $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, or $x>y$ causing $y \in A$.  By supposition, $y > \sup A$ and $y < \inf A^*$, so neither $x>y$ nor $x<y$.  Therefore $x=y$ and $x \in \mathbb{Q}$.  This means the only rational number missing from $A \cup A^*$ is $x$ and we must have $\sup A = x = \inf A^*$.

Comment: However, neither $A$ nor $A^{*}$ are rational sets and in fact $x$ could not be the supremum or the infimum of these. It is $a^{x}$. but this is definition, that is, you define $a^{x}=\sup\{a^{r}\mid r<x,r\in\mathbb{Q}\}$, for example. Moreover $x$ needs not to be rational, it could be $\pi$, $\sqrt{2}$, $e$ or any irrational.

Comment: I can use your response, as you used my question in your deleted answer, in order to speculate. Suppose $\sup A$ is strictly less than $\inf A^*$, then there is a $a^{y}$ such that $\sup A < a^{y} < \inf A^*$. Then $y$ must be such that $x<y$ and $y<x$ at the same time, what is a contradiction and therefore there's no such $a^{y}$. It follows that $\sup A=\inf a^{*}$. However the problem would be, how to justify that if $\sup A<\inf A^{*}$ then there is some $a^{y}$, with $y\in\mathbb{Q}$, between them? If that is possible, then this comment is the right answer, thanks to your last answer.